# the browser goes slowly when i use this

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, browser

HTML:

```
<a class="myAnchor">asd1<img class="imagenmangue" alt="" src="/images/asd1.jpg" height="215" width="430""></a>
```

css:

```
a.myAnchor img{visibility:hidden}
a.myAnchor:hover img{visibility:visible}
```

Script:

```
/*  move the image  */
$('.myAnchor').hover(function(){     
  $(document).on( "mousemove", function( event ) {
  if ($( document ).width() > 800) {
     $(".imagenmangue").css({left: (event.pageX - $('.tabs_type_2').offset().left + 15),top: (event.pageY - $('.tabs_type_2').offset().top - 35)});
  }  else {
 };
});
}, function(){      
});
```

I´m doing this so the image moves with the mouse, when it is on the a:hover. But the browser goes slowly. How can i solve this?

Comment: What you're looking for is throttle and/or debounce.

Comment: I'm looking for both, but mostly the debounce!

Comment: @user3704434 have you tried using that yourself?

Comment: yes, I've tried. But I'm really new on this and i don't understand to much.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you hover over the element you are adding a new event listener to the document! You are overloading the mousemove. You want to only add one mousemove event. Either remove the event when done or add the event once and set a flag when you want it to run.

Comment: Thank you! I am learning and do not understand much of this, how can I do any of those two things? Remove the event or use a flag?

Comment: @Francisco you can use a flag, or set the element once on the document ready event: `$(document).ready(function(){/*Set mousemove event handler here*/});`

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by user epascarello, you can attach the event listener **once** to the element itself, rather than to add a new one to the document every time you hover `.myAnchor`. So instead of declaring it like this:

```
/* Every time .myAnchor gets hovered */
$('.myAnchor').hover(function(){     
    /* Create a new event listener that listens to the mouse movements inside the document */
    $(document).on( "mousemove", function( event ) {
        /* do stuff here */
    });
});
```

You can declare it like this:

```
/* When the mouse moves over .myAnchor */
$(document).on( "mousemove", ".myAnchor", function( event ) { 
    /* do stuff here */
}
```

I've created a JSFiddle with more a more in-depth explanation of what's going on in your code, you can check it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/M7bWS/